# Internal Server on a dynamic php script that works well on other options

Tags: php, server

I have a php script that generates report sheet of a class in a school. With other school classes selected the report sheet script works just fine but when you select this particular class it shows Internal Server Error

Peep the code be

```css
<?php
session_start();
ob_flush();
include('server_func.inc');
//ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
//ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '60000');
ini_set('memory_limit','12560M');
//set_time_limit('60000');   
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout','-1');   
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$session = $_GET['session'];

$term = $_GET['term'];

//$classID = $_GET['classID'];

$config = system_config('TEST');



if(isset($_REQUEST['session']))

{

    $session = $_REQUEST['session'];

}

else

{

    echo 'No session selected';

    exit;

}



if(isset($_REQUEST['term']))

{

    $term = $_REQUEST['term'];

}

else

{

    echo 'No term selected';

    exit;

}


if(isset($_REQUEST['classID']))

{

    $classID = $_REQUEST['classID'];
$class_list =  class_list_view($session,$classID,'');
}



if(isset($_REQUEST['StudentID']))

{

    $StudentID  = $_REQUEST['StudentID'];
    $classID = getStudentClass($session,$StudentID);
    $class_list =  class_list_view($session,$classID,$StudentID);
    //if($_SESSION['school_id']==8)
//{
//echo "Check back later";
//break;
//}

}

else

{

    $StudentID = '';

}




$cAverage = 0.0;

$totalScore = 0.0;

$fAverage = 0.0;

$hAverage = 0.0;

$lAverage = 0.0;

$current_session = current_session();

//$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT s1.StudentID, s2.StudentID FROM sch_student s1 INNER JOIN sch_student_list ON s1.StudentID = s2.StudentID WHERE ClassID =  '$classID' AND Session ='$session'");
//$allstudents = mysql_num_rows($q1);

//$class_list =  class_list_view($session,$classID,'');
//$class_list3 =classList_search($classID,'',$session);
//$class_list2 =  class_list_view($session,$classID,$StudentID);
$noClass = count($class_list);
//echo $noClass;

$student = student_view_1('','');

$classview = class_view($classID);

$classRoom = $classview[0];



$timetable = timeTable_view_s($classID);

$subjects = subject_view_1('');



$sectionID = $classRoom->getSectionID();

$format_view = array();

//$subjectID = '';

//$StudentID = '';

$section = section_display($sectionID);

$assessment = assessment_display($section->getAssessmentID());



$grading = grading_display($section->getGradingID());




if($grading != null)

$grading_format_view = grading_format_view($grading->getGradingID(),'');



$assessment = section_assessment_view($sectionID,$session,$term);
$ass_id = $assessment[0]['assessment_format_id'];
if(count($assessment)<1){
    echo "No Assessment chosen for this section";
}
else {
$format_view = assessment_format_view_clone($ass_id);
}



$scores = scores_view('');



//$result_view = result_view($subjectID,$StudentID,$classID);

$result_view = result_view_students($class_list,$session,$term);



$stud = getSubjectResults($result_view,$format_view,$scores);

$traits_view_section  =  traits_view_section($sectionID);

$traits = traits_view_s($session,$term,$section->getSectionID());

$staff_view = staff_display($classRoom->getFormTeacher(),'');

$rs = getFormattedStudent($result_view,$format_view,$scores);

$divider = 'ByClass';       
$timetable_viewnew = timeTable_view($classID,'');
$check[] = '';
for($i=0;$i<count($timetable_viewnew);$i++)
    {

            $subjectID1 = $timetable_viewnew[$i]->getSubjectID();
            $tag1 = $timetable_viewnew[$i]->getTag();
            //if($tag=='Ancillary')
            $check[] = $tag1;
    }
    if(in_array("Ancillary",$check)){
        $divider = 'ByStudent';
    }
//$html = '

?>

<style type="text/css">

      * {

    }
    .page {
        width: 21cm;
        min-height: 26cm;
        margin: 0.2cm auto;

    }
    .subpage {
    padding: 0.1cm;

    }

    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }
    @media print {
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }


 .rsBox
 {

    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    border-image:url(img/border.png) 30 30 round;
-moz-border-image:url(img/border.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url(img/border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-border-image:url(img/border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
padding:5px;    
overflow:hidden;
 }

 .block
 {
    width: 95%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #666666;
 }

 .seperator
 {
 height: 20px;
 }

 .name
 {
    height: 43px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform:uppercase;

 }

 .motto
 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
 }

 .address
 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 95%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
 }

 .session
 {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
 }

 .over_border
 {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #333333; 
 }

 .section1 td

 {

    font-size: 14px; 

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    border:1px solid #999;  



 }



 .overview td

 {

    border-right-width: 1px;

    border-right-style: solid;

    border-right-color: #333333; 



    border-bottom-width: 1px;

    border-bottom-style: solid;

    border-bottom-color: #333333; 

 }



 .trait .td

 {

    border-width: 1px;

    border-style: solid;

    border-color: #333333; 

 }



 .ob

 {



    font-size: 12px; 

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

 }



 .tob

 {



    font-size: 12px; 

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

 }



  .obs

 {



    font-size: 11px; 

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

 } 

.subjectsDiv {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0px;
    background:#FFF;

}
.subjectsDivTd {

    height:100px;
    max-width:20px;
    min-width:20px;
    border:1px solid;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#000;
}

</style>

<div class="book">

<?php
$newsletter = '';

      $data =  newsletter_view('',$sectionID,$session,$term);

            for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
                $newsletter = $data[$i]['content'];
            }
$i = 0;

if(empty($class_list)){

echo "No class member"; 

}

else

foreach($class_list as $std):

//$i++;

//if($i>10)

//break;



$StudentID  = $std->getStudentID();
if($student[$StudentID]==NULL){
continue;
}

$cAverage = 0.0;

$totalScore = 0.0;

$fAverage = 0.0;

$hAverage = 0.0;

$lAverage = 0.0;

$index = 0;



$results = $result_view[$std->getStudentID()];

$index = 0;

$noSubjects = 0;



if(!empty($results))

foreach($results as $result)

            {
            $resultID = $result->getResultID();

            $mark = 0;

            $totality = 0;

            $subjectID = trim($result->getSubjectID());

           if(!empty($stud[$subjectID]))

            $subject = $stud[$subjectID];

            if(!empty($format_view)):

            foreach($format_view as $format):

            if(isset($scores[$resultID][$format->getFormatID()]))
            {
                $score = $scores[$resultID][$format->getFormatID()];

                $mark = $score->getScore();

                $totalScore += $mark;
            }



            endforeach;

        endif;



        $index++;

        $cAverage += getSubjectAverage($subject,$noClass);

}





if(!empty($cAverage))

$cAverage /= $index;

if(!empty($fAverage))

$fAverage = $totalScore / $index;



$formatting = getGradeFormat($grading_format_view,round($fAverage,0));

$grade = 'N/A';

if($formatting != null)

$grade = $formatting->getDescriptor();



//$html .=

$comment = comment_view($StudentID,$session,$term);

for($l=0; $l<count($comment); $l++){

    $cc = $comment[$l];

    $formteacher_comment = $cc->getFormteacher();

    $principal_comment = $cc->getPrincipal();





}

$bscores = count($results);

$cscores = $bscores * 100;

if(!empty($totalScore))

//$percentage = round($totalScore/$cscores * 100,0)."%";
echo $cscores;
$percentage = round($totalScore/$cscores * 100,2);
if($divider=="ByStudent") { 
$percentage = round($totalScore/$cscores * 100,2);
 } 
 else { 
    $percentage = round($totalScore/count($timetable_viewnew),2);
  }; 
//$totalScore/$cscores * 100;

?>



<a href='#' onclick='window.print()'><img src='images/print_icon.jpg' width='50' height='30' /></a>
<div class="page">

        <div class="subpage">



          <div class="rsBox">

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


  <tr style="height:auto;">

    <td height="" align="center" >

    <div  style="width:auto; height:auto; overflow:auto; border-bottom:1px solid;">

    <div style="border:0px solid; width:10%; height:100px; float:left; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;  ">

    <img src="<?php echo $config->getLogo(); ?>" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />

    </div>

    <div style="border:0px solid; width:78%; float:left;">

    <h4 style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px;">ARCHDIOCESE OF ONITSHA</h4>

    <div class="name"><?php echo $config->getSchoolname(); ?></div>



    <div class="address"><?php echo  $config->getAddress(); ?></div>

    <div class="session"> REPORT SHEET FOR <?php echo $term . ', ' . $session ; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;ACADEMIC SESSION</div>

    </div>

  <div style="border:0px solid; width:10%; height:100px; float:left; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;  ">
    <img src="images/micolos.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />
    </div>



    </div>



    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td><table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="section1">

      <tr>

        <td width="19%" align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">NAME::</td>

        <td width="1%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td width="43%"><?php echo $student[$StudentID]->getFirstname(). ' ' .$student[$StudentID]->getMiddlename().' '. $student[$StudentID]->getLastname(); ?></td>

        <td width="20%" align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Mark Obtainable: </td>

        <td width="1%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td width="16%"><?php echo $cscores ;?></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">CLASS::</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><?php echo  $classRoom->getLevel() .   ' ' . $classRoom->getPrefix(); ?></td>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Total:: </td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><?php echo $totalScore; ?></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Admission No:: </td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><?php echo  $student[$StudentID]->getRegno(); ?></td>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Average:</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><?php if(!empty($percentage)) echo  $percentage; ?>&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Session::</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><?php echo $session; ?></td>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Position:</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td>&nbsp;<?php 

        echo getTermPosition($rs,$StudentID); 

        $pos = getTermPosition($rs,$StudentID); 

         if($pos == '11'){

                 echo 'th';

}

        elseif($pos == 12){

                 echo 'th';

}

        elseif($pos == 13){

                 echo 'th';

}

        elseif(substr($pos, -1)=='1') { echo 'st'; } 



        else if(substr($pos, -1)=='2') { echo 'nd'; }

        else if(substr($pos, -1)=='3') { echo 'rd'; }



        else  { echo 'th'; }



         ?></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Term:</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><?php echo  $term; ?></td>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>

        <tr>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">Next Term Begins</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><?php echo  $current_session->getNextTerm(); ?></td>

        <td align="left" style="font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;</td>

        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>



    </table></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>

    <div class="block"><span style="font-weight:bold;">No. in Class :: <?php echo $noClass; ?></span></div>

    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

<td>

<div class="block">

GRADE: <br />

<?php



foreach($grading_format_view as $b) { 

       $desc = $b->getDescriptor();

       $start = $b->getStart();

       $end = $b->getEnd();

       echo '<b>'.$desc.'</b>'.'='.$start.'-'.$end.','.' ';

     }



     ?>

</div>

</td>

</tr>

  <tr>

    <td>

    <div class="block">



    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="overview">

      <tr class="ob">

        <td align="center" width="25%">SUBJECT</td>



          <?php 

        if(!empty($format_view)):

            foreach($format_view as $format):





       ?>

      <!-- // $html .= -->

        <td valign="bottom" align="center"> <?php echo $format->getShortName(); ?><br>

 <?php echo '('. $format->getPercentage() . '%)'; ?></td>

<?php

            endforeach;

        endif;



      // $html .=

      ?>

      <td valign="bottom" align="center">TOTAL</td>
 <!-- <td valign="bottom" align="center">POSITION</td>-->
      <td valign="bottom" align="center">GRADE </td>

        <td align="center" valign="bottom" style="width:120px;">COMMENT</td>

        <td valign="bottom" align="center">Subject Master Signature</td>

      </tr>



      <?php

     if(!empty($results))

            foreach($results as $result)

            {

            $subjectID = $result->getSubjectID();

            //if($timetable[$subjectID]->getTag()!='Compulsory')

            //{

                //continue;

            //}



            $subject = $stud[$subjectID];

            arsort($subject);



            $noSubjects++;

            $index++;

            $resultID = $result->getResultID();

            $mark = "";

            $totality = 0;





     //$html .= 

     ?>

     <tr class="obs">

        <td align="left">  <?php if(!empty($subjects[$subjectID])) { echo $subjects[$subjectID]->getTitle(); } else { echo $subjectID; } ?> </td>



        <?php
$mark = '-';
        if(!empty($format_view)):

            foreach($format_view as $format):

            if(isset($scores[$resultID][$format->getFormatID()]))

            {

                $score = $scores[$resultID][$format->getFormatID()];

                if(empty($score)){
                    $mark = '-';
                }
                 else {
                $mark = $score->getScore();
                 }

                $totality += $mark;

                $totalScore += $mark;

            }


        ?>

    <!-- //  $html .= -->  

       <td align="center"> <?php echo  $mark; ?> </td>

        <?php

            endforeach;

        endif;



        $formatter = getGradeFormat($grading_format_view,$totality);



       // $html .= 

       ?>

          <td align="center"><?php echo $totality; ?></td>
 <!-- <td align="center"><?php //echo  getSubjectPosition($subject,$resultID) ; ?></td>-->
         <td align="center"><?php echo $formatter->getDescriptor(); ?></td>

         <td align="center"><?php  echo $formatter->getComment(); ?></td>

         <td>.</td>

        </tr>

    <?php

      }





     if(!empty($totalScore))

      $average = $totalScore/ $noSubjects;



   //$html .=

   ?>

    </table>



</div></td></tr>




<tr><td>
<div class="block">

<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="trait" style="float:left; border:0px;">
<tr>
 <td style="border:0px;"> 
 <!--  Rating Details::-->
  <?php

   $trait_rating_view = view_section_traits(view_section_trait_rating_format($sectionID));
    //echo $trait_rating_view;

    for($j=0; $j<(count($trait_rating_view)); $j++){
     $trait_rating_s = $trait_rating_view[$j]; 

    ?>
    <b>
    <?php

    //echo  $trait_rating_view[$j]['rating'];?></b><!--=--><?php //echo  $trait_rating_view[$j]['description'].','.' '; ?>
     <?php
     }
     ?>

 </td>
 </tr>
      <tr class="tob" style="border:0px;" >

         <td style="border:0px;">

           <table>
            <tr>
              <td >
              <?php
              if(!empty($traits))
  foreach($traits as $format):


  ?>

    <div style="min-width:180px; min-height:80px; border:0px solid; float:left; position:relative; margin-right:4px;" >

      <table border="1" style="max-width:180px; border:1px solid #CCC;">
       <tr>
        <td style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;"><?php echo $format->getTraitDesc(); ?></td>  <?php
        $t_format_view = traits_definition_view($format->getTriatID());
            if(!empty($t_format_view)):
            for($u=0; $u<count($t_format_view); $u++):
             $t_format  = $t_format_view[$u];


            // $traits_rating_format = 
            //$rating = get_student_trait_rating($StudentID,$t_format->getTraitID(),$t_format->getTraitDefinitionID())
             ?>

                <td style="font-size:11px;" class="subjectsDivTd"><div class="subjectsDiv"> <?php echo $t_format->getDefinition(); ?></div> </td>


             <?php

             endfor;
             endif;
             ?>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;">Rating</td><?php
        $t_format_view = traits_definition_view($format->getTriatID());
            if(!empty($t_format_view)):
            for($u=0; $u<count($t_format_view); $u++):
             $t_format  = $t_format_view[$u];


            // $traits_rating_format = 
            //$rating = get_student_trait_rating($StudentID,$t_format->getTraitID(),$t_format->getTraitDefinitionID())
             ?>

                <td><?php
                 if(get_student_trait_rating($StudentID,$t_format->getTraitID(),$t_format->getTraitDefinitionID(),$session,'Third Term')==NULL){ echo " ";} 
                 else { get_student_trait_rating($StudentID,$t_format->getTraitID(),$t_format->getTraitDefinitionID(),$session,'Third Term'); }  ?> </td>

             <?php

             endfor;
             endif;
             ?>
        </tr>



        </table>
    </div>

  <?php

  endforeach;
  ?>

            </td>
            </tr>
            </table></td></tr></table></div>

           <tr>
           <td>
          <div class="rsBox">
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="trait" style="float:left;" border="1">
   <tr class="tob">
        <td style="max-width:80px;"><strong>Class Manager:</strong></td>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"><?php if(!empty($staff_view)){echo $staff_view->getTitle().' '.$staff_view->getFirstname().' '.$staff_view->getMiddlename().' '.$staff_view->getLastname();} else { echo ".";} ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tob">
        <td style="max-width:80px;"><strong>Class Manager Remark:</strong></td>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"><?php  if(!empty($formteacher_comment)){ echo $formteacher_comment; } else { echo ".";} ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tob">
        <td style="max-width:80px;"><strong>School Head Remark</strong>:</td>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"><?php if(!empty($principal_comment)) { echo $principal_comment; } else { echo ".";} ?></td>
      </tr>
       <tr class="tob">
        <td style="max-width:80px;"><strong>School Head/Principal</strong>:</td>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"><?php echo 
$section->getSectionHead();  ?></td>
      </tr>
       <tr class="tob">
        <td style="max-width:80px;"><strong>School Head/Principal Signature</strong>:</td>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"><img src="<?php echo $section->getSectionHeadSignature(); ?>" width="120" height="40" /></td>
      </tr>

</table>

</div>
</td></tr>

</table>

          </div>

        </div>


    </div>  
    <div class="seperator"></div>

    <?php
    if($newsletter==""){
        continue;
    }
        else {
        ?>
    <div class="book">


<div class="page" style="height:300xp;">

        <div class="subpage">



          <div class="rsBox">


<?php 
echo $newsletter;
?>

          </div>
    </div>

        </div>

    <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
endforeach;

//$html .=
?>
 </div>
 <?php
/*if($_REQUEST['op'] == 'PDF' )
{
 require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"); 

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($classRoom->getLevel() .' ' . $classRoom->getPrefix() . ' ' . "result.pdf");
}
else
{
echo $html;*/
?>


<?php
//}
?>

<script type="javascript">
 window.print();
</script>
```

Comment: that's good that other class selections work, but when you say "when you select this particular class" which class selection are you talking about?

Comment: What i mean is that you have student classes in the app eg Standard 1 A, Standard 1 B, etc. not php classes.

Comment: yeah but which class shows the error?

Comment: BASIC 1 A. The others loads just fine. i guess its a problem from the script